# How do you tell if the ratio of Strings to char[] in a heap dump is indicative of an issue?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

An application is exceeding the expected amount of memory allocated to it, and the top three entries in the heap dump are as follows:

```
 num     #instances    #mb          class name
----------------------------------------------
 1:      11759890      465.61       [C
 2:       3659043      292.89       [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
 3:      11762204      282.29       java.lang.String
```

As strings are represented by char arrays, it is expected to see a correlation between the two, and in this case the number of instances of each are fairly similar, with only a difference of ~3000 instances.
What appears confusing is the disparity in usage of the two, given char[] constitute over 50% more bytes than Strings.
As the program in question does not directly contain instances of char arrays, (although there may be a dependency which does that I have overlooked), it seems as if the char arrays are the sole source, but due to the memory usage I am unsure of if this is expected.

What are the expected ratios between char arrays and strings with respect to instances and memory usage? At what point would the data suggest a leak with one of the two?

Comment: Taking your last question literally, the answer must be that these data *never* suggest a memory leak. These statistics are not capable of hinting about memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Java 7, update 6 a `String` instance consisted of reference to a `char[]` array and two `int` fields, `offset` and `length`. Together with the JVM specific object overhead of at least two words for HotSpot, it can explain the average of 24 bytes per `String` in your statistics.

In contrast, a `char[]` array has the JVM specific object overhead, a length stored as `int` and a *variable sized* content. So seeing a significantly bigger memory usage, like the average of 40 bytes per `char[]` array shown in your statistics, is not unusual. Without knowing more about your specific JVM configuration, it’s a bit guesswork, but if we assume 16 bytes for the array header, including length and perhaps padding, the remaining 24 bytes suggest an average array size of 12 `char`s, which is not unreasonable.

Starting with Java 7, update 6, the `offset` and `length` fields of `String` are gone, which should reduce the size to 16 bytes per instance for most configurations, which could save you ~100MB for the string instances. And change the ratio significantly, so `char[]` instances dominate the heap even more.

Which is the reason why starting with Java 9, `String` instances consist of just a reference to a `byte[]` array. If the string consists of iso-latin-1 characters only, which applies to a lot of strings in typical applications, it will use only one byte per character, halving the amount of memory for these strings (for their array, to be precise). Since there will be also strings with characters outside that charset, of course, the saving won’t be exactly like that. But perhaps another ~100MB for your application.

But still, assuming the average string length guessed above, the memory used by these arrays will be significantly bigger than the memory used by the string instances, even under the most recent implementations. That’s normal.